# Creating a video from set of images Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, animationdrawable, jcodec

I am working on an app for android that creates video file from a video at start and then set of images, and saves it.
Is there any way to accomplish that?

I tried JCodec and it has broken libraries, untrusted code on the web and lack of knowledge about this library.

I tried FFMpeg and it is unsupported enough on android and involves working with NDK.

I tried to create an animation with AnimationDrawable and save this animation as a video, but I can't find a way to save animation as video except using the feature of KITKAT 4.4, but it requires connecting to a computer and having a root.

Is there any other solutions or a trusted and explained way to do this using the ways above?

Thank in advance

Comment: If you can render it with GLES, you can record a .mp4 video using MediaCodec and MediaMuxer.  Requires API 18+.  Some examples on http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ and https://github.com/google/grafika .

Comment: @fadden: what's special about GLES in the solution you propose?

Comment: It's used to provide Surface input to MediaCodec.  You can't do that with software rendering on a Canvas (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61194).  I agree with your answer -- ffmpeg is a better choice unless you only care about API 18+.

Comment: @fadden: if you use MediaMuxer to simply write to a local mp4 file, you cam later play this file anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would vote for FFMPEG. You don't need NDK or other sourcery if you can afford a prebuilt solution, like [FFmpeg 4 Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android).

Comment: Link is dead, is there any mirror link?